# シェルスクリプトでfor文のコマンド出力をパイプでつないだ時のコマンド実行順序

Tags: bash, shellscript

以下シェルスクリプトがあるとします。

```
for i in `seq 5`
do
  echo ${i} # cmd1
done | cat # cmd2
```

このとき、パイプでつながれたcatコマンドはforのループが終了してから起動されるのでしょうか？
それとも、ループと並行して起動し、echoの出力が都度送り込まれるような動きになるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スクリプト名を `test.sh` として、strace コマンドで処理を追跡してみます。これを見て考えてみて下さい。

```sh
$ strace -tt -f -e dup2,execve,write ./test.sh
17:59:49.438629 execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], 0x7ffddf147b30 /* 81 vars */) = 0
17:59:49.440768 dup2(3, 255)            = 255
strace: Process 145782 attached
strace: Process 145783 attached
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.441452 dup2(3, 0) = 0
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.441493 dup2(4, 1) = 1
strace: Process 145784 attached
[pid 145784] 17:59:49.441858 dup2(4, 1) = 1
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.442112 execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat"], 0x560ddec53970 /* 81 vars */) = 0
[pid 145784] 17:59:49.442490 execve("/usr/bin/seq", ["seq", "5"], 0x560ddec53970 /* 81 vars */) = 0
[pid 145784] 17:59:49.443350 write(1, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n", 10) = 10
[pid 145784] 17:59:49.443487 +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443526 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=145784, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443638 write(1, "1\n", 2) = 2
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443667 write(1, "1\n", 21
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443684 write(1, "2\n", 2 <unfinished ...>
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443701 <... write resumed>) = 2
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443709 <... write resumed>) = 2
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443729 write(1, "3\n", 2 <unfinished ...>
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443742 write(1, "2\n", 22
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443754 <... write resumed>) = 2
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443775 <... write resumed>) = 2
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443808 write(1, "4\n", 2) = 2
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443870 write(1, "5\n", 2 <unfinished ...>
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443891 write(1, "3\n4\n", 4 <unfinished ...>
3
4
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.443902 <... write resumed>) = 2
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443911 <... write resumed>) = 4
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.443937 write(1, "5\n", 25
) = 2
[pid 145782] 17:59:49.444017 +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 145783] 17:59:49.444158 +++ exited with 0 +++
17:59:49.444622 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=145782, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
17:59:49.444817 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: 並行して動いてますね！

Answer (score 1):

パイプの継続のコマンドによって ループは中断されることもあります。
(以下のような場合に, 該当するファイルが見つかればその後は必要ない, などのとき)

```
$ for f in ~/data/*; do echo $f; done | ファイル選択処理
```

例えばループの数値が大きくても, 後続のコマンドが一瞬で終了する場合, ループもすぐに終了するでしょう。同時に動いてないと無理です

```
$ time for i in `seq 600000`; do echo ${i}; done >/dev/null 

real    0m2.910s
user    0m2.657s
sys 0m0.280s

$ time for i in `seq 600000`; do echo ${i}; done | python -V
Python 3.10.4

real    0m0.349s
user    0m0.284s
sys 0m0.117s
```

Answer (score 1):

> このとき、パイプでつながれたcatコマンドはforのループが終了してから起動されるのでしょうか？
> それとも、ループと並行して起動し、echoの出力が都度送り込まれるような動きになるのでしょうか？

パイプでつながれたcmd2はforのループの終了をまたずに起動されます。

質問の例のスクリプトはcmd1がすぐに終了するので、cmd1とcmd2が並行するのを確認できません。

すぐに終了しないコマンドをcmd1とした場合、cmd1とcmd2が並行することを確認できます。
cmd1：yesコマンド
cmd2：lessコマンド

```sh
for i in `seq 5`
do
    yes # cmd1
done | less # cmd2
```

この例ではcmd1がずっとyを標準出力に書き続けますが、cmd2はforのループが終了をまたずに標準入力から受け取ったデータを表示(標準出力)します。

Answer (score -2):

試しに上記`shellscript`を以下のように改造してみました

```
#/bin/sh
for i in `seq 5`
do
  echo ${i} # cmd1
done | echo $$ #cmd2
```

結果はプロセス番号が1行しか表示されなかったので、`for`のループが終了してからパイプが起動されると思われます。